# Splitting a paragraph line by line in c++

Tags: c++

Hello I am a cs140 student so I am not the most experienced. I have an assignment and basically I have to find the longest line in a string vector. First I have to take paragraph as input. How do I take the input from a file and split it line by line into a string vector? Please go easy on me

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show a [mre] and any error messages

Comment: Hint: look at `std::ifstream`, `std::string`, `std::vector`, `std::getline()`, `while`, and `std::vector::push_back()`.

Comment: What is the name of the cs140 class?  Which university or college?  Not all universities and colleges have the numbering or class subjects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you don't usually read the text and *then* split it line by line. Instead, you read the text line by line in the first place, using the getline function

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

You can choose to store all the lines in a vector of strings, however, in order to find the longest string, you don't have to store all of them. You can just compare the current line's length with a saved "longest line" or the length thereof.

Comment: Pay special attention to that last bit of advice. don't store anything you don't have to. Not only does it waste resources, it almost always results in a more complicated program. If you can get away with only holding the current value and a minimum, maximum, sum, or some other statistic, do it.